# Webview2 AddHostObjectToScript throws Exception thrown at 0x7901179F

Tags: .net, webview2, winui-3

I have a test WinUI 3 application using a WebView2 where I want to be able to call C# code from the hosted JavaScript.

Following [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.addhostobjecttoscript?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1054.31), I have the following:

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class Bridge
{
  public string Func(string param)
  {
   return "Example: " + param;
  }
}
...

   await MyWebView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
    
    MyWebView.CoreWebView2.SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping(
     "appassets", "assets", CoreWebView2HostResourceAccessKind.Allow);
    
    MyWebView.Source = new Uri("http://appassets/www/index.html");
    MyWebView.CoreWebView2.OpenDevToolsWindow();
    
    MyWebView.CoreWebView2.AddHostObjectToScript("bridge", new Bridge());
```

However, the call to `AddHostObjectToScript` gives me:

> Exception thrown at 0x7901179F (Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll) in WinUI3_1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

[image]

### Update 1

Following the suggestion of @Poul Bak, I added my call to `NavigationCompleted`, but unfortunately it did not help.

[image]

Also, I should add that I am using VS2019, where I added the WinUI3 support via manage extensions, so hopefully my error is not due to this.

Comment: I suggest you try to set the host object in the `NavigationCompleted` event. That way the page is fully working, when you set the host object.

Comment: Editor's note: peterc, your questions are quite good. They seem to have an appropriate level of detail, and thus they look (at first glance) to be answerable. However, they are let down by a needy, begging tone, which is generally discouraged here - technical writing is preferred. Indeed, an ingratiating or pleading tone [does not generally improve answer rates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions), and may just earn you downvotes instead.

Comment: Your questions also seem to have a subtle implication that you would like to give out parcels of work to people - does anyone know X? Can anyone help? These are all actions for other people. As an engineer, it is better for you to believe that you can do it yourself, or that you will be doing the bulk of the work: How to foo the bar? How can I bop the widget? etc. You may find that if you take on the mantle of self-actualisation that you can fix more things than you think you can, but moreover, your posts will get a better response too.

Comment: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/2015

Comment: Noted @PoulBak. I will delete one now for brevity, and of course the question author can flag them (NLN) when they have read them. As an editor I find that the most effective way to encourage writers to keep to house style is to explain why we have those preferences. I assure you, I would much rather it was not necessary!

Comment: I added some info following @Paulk Bak suggestion. Also someone else has reported this [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/2015), so I have added my 5 cents worth. Note it is on;y a problem in WinUI3, it works fine in a WPF application

Comment: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/2529 - here is more recent updates on it - so far no solution AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, with WebView2, we can only give access to the class and not directly inject an object (`new Bridge()`) like we did with WebView. We have to create an object on the web end.

FYI - [Kristen Schau](https://github.com/krschau) provided a solution for this in https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/7170#issuecomment-1215910370

Here is the solution in short: To give access, follow the steps from the guide that Microsoft provides for [calling native-side WinRT code from web-side code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/how-to/winrt-from-js?tabs=csharp) with the below changes before Step 6:

1. Add **CsWinRT** nuget package to **webview2_sample_uwp** project
2. Add the following lines to **webview2_sample_uwp** csproj

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CsWinRTIncludes>WinRTAdapter</CsWinRTIncludes>
  </PropertyGroup>
```